# Is Azure.ConfigurationManager compatible with .Net Core?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using .Net Core v1.0, and would like to use Azure Table Storage in my application. I successfully installed the Azure.Storage package via NuGet, but when I install the Azure.ConfigurationManager package I get this error when I do a dotnet restore:

```
Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0).
Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

Is there a way around this? Can I still use Azure Table Storage without the ConfigurationManager?

Thanks!

**Edit (October 4th, 2016):**
It appears you can use Azure Table Storage without ConfigurationManager, but you won't be able to access and modify application settings during runtime. [Storage Configure Connection String - Parsing a Connection String](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-configure-connection-string/#parsing-a-connection-string)

Comment: You could add an answer yourself if you found an answer :)
And that won't be a problem since you can use the standard ASP.NET Core settings for storing the connection string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Azure.ConfigurationManager is not compatible with .NET Core.**

ConfigurationManager is optional, so is not required for use of Azure Table Storage. Also as a replacement you can use the .NET Framework's [ConfigurationManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

[Storage Configure Connection String - Parsing a Connection String](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-configure-connection-string/#parsing-a-connection-string)